# Custom typespec for Elixir function to ensure like dimensionality of two lists used as arguments for a function

Tags: elixir, linear-algebra

I am working on re-implementing some basic linear algebra functionalities of NumPy/SciPy in Elixir. Don't worry, I know this is a somewhat frivolous endeavor. I just am doing it for fun.

Currently I already have a bunch of working functions, but especially with vectors I want to add some custom behaviours.
The simplest example would be this. Let's say I have a function `add_vectors/2`:

```
def add_vectors(vec_1, vec_2) do
  for {el_1, el_2} <- Enum.zip(vec_1, vec_2), do: el_1 + el_2
end
```

I could easily adorn it with:

```
@spec add_vectors(list(), list()) :: list()
```

But, this only checks that the type is simply in fact a list.
I know you can define custom typespecs in elixir, but I do not want to have to write a macro that goes through to define it for any dimensionality N.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you want to write a typespec that tells the vectors/lists length/dimension? I'm pretty sure that's out of scope for typespecs since these are meant to define specifications for **types** like the name implies. Per the docs:

> Elixir comes with a notation for declaring types and specifications. Elixir is dynamically typed, as such typespecs are never used by the compiler to optimize or modify code. Still, using typespecs is useful as documentation and tools such as Dialyzer can analyze the code with typespecs to find bugs.

Looking at the docs I don't find any mention of validating and specifying function properties that must be ensured. What you're looking for seems more akin to tools like Java's JML for design by contract where such properties are validated. I suggest you take a look at Design by Contract for Elixir:

[Elixir Contracts](https://github.com/epsanchezma/elixir-contracts)

[Talk about the project](http://www.erlang-factory.com/berlin2015/elba-sanchez)

You may also utilize guards and pattern matching if you want to program defensively for that kind of functions (look for the `when` macro).